# linux tcp/ip : Is there any chance that packet is acknowledged but dropped for any reason?

Tags: linux, tcp

I assume that network card handles the tcp acknowledgement. but after acknowledgement , till packet reaches the app layer, is any there any chance, packet is dropped for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

> > I assume that network card handles the tcp acknowledgement. but after acknowledgement , till packet reaches the app layer, is any there any chance, packet is dropped for any reason.

No. Network card does not handle TCP acknowledgement. It is the TCP layer itself. Packets be will be ACKed as and when they arrive. Application even need to call `recv`. It will be removed from buffer once the application reads from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The network card does not handle the TCP acks (except for some quite expensive devices that [offload the entire stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine) into hardware).

At best it'll be [accelerating the calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#checksum_offload) of the network checksums for you but not much else beyond its core [datalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=OSI_model#Layer_2:_Data_Link_Layer) and [physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=OSI_model#Layer_1:_Physical_Layer) MAC and PHY tasks.

The acks are handled by the TCP module at layer 4 and no, there is no chance of data being dropped between layer 4 and the application layer. If you are too slow to consume data from the application API then TCP implements flow control by '[closing the window](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/10/tcp-sliding-window/)' to the sender to prevent it from sending more data than you have available in your network buffers.